# How to see all the output from the PHP internal server start without breaking unit tests?

Tags: php, phpunit

If I launch the following command :

```sh
php -S localhost:-50 -t ./web web/index.php
```

It will work as expected, that is to say, I saw this line at first :

> Invalid address: localhost:-50

However, it will not work in PHPUnit. Indeed, this will stop the script. So, I have added redirections to let PHPUnit continue and successfully test my code :

```sh
php -S localhost:-50 -t ./web web/index.php 2>&1
```

But then if I do add those redirections, I will not see anymore this line when using correct ports :

> [Fri May 21 11:32:33 2021] PHP 8.0.5 Development Server (http://localhost:8000) started

And I will not see all errors that can occur when I navigate on the site.

How can I have the best of both worlds? Full output (information and errors) in my console and PHPUnit that succeeds to launch my unit test about PHP internal server?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve/test with a port of `-50`?

Comment: This is just an example. I use this value in tests only, to checks what happens when a user puts a wrong port as I want to test every scenario.